# Site Footer Get Behind the Sidebar on Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

Hi I am having little issue with my site mobile visibility. Site sidebar and footer is accurate on desktop but on mobile the footer get behind the sidebar "contact us form".

Here is my site: http://dysarthomestay.com.au

Also, there is issue with menu. One menu "Price List" is not showing on mobile.

Immediate help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the appropriate bits of HTML and CSS so we can look into your issue! Also, try to limit your questions to one issue at a time unless they're closely related which these don't seem to be. Thanks!

Comment: Here is the code used for sidebar:

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in the fact that your `.online_reservation` class is on `position:absolute`. Just set it to `position:static`, so like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
.online_reservation {
  position: static;
  right: 25px;
  width: 90%;
  z-index: 99;
  display: block;
}
```

Edit this for all other resolutions too.

Comment: Thanks It works. Could you please also tell me how to display the menu option "Price List" on mobile.

Comment: Of course! On line 119 of your `index.php` file, you have set the Price List list item to be commented out: `<!---<li><a href="things_to_do.php">Price List</a></li>--->`. Change this line to be `<li><a href="things_to_do.php">Price List</a></li>` and Price List will appear in the list again. Don't forget to mark my answer as the solution if it helped.